# TS2339 - 'Property doesn't exist on type' error in an apparently valid TS file

Tags: typescript

I have the following type declarations:

```
type Root = { r: string };
type A = { a: string };
type B = { b: string };
type Main = Root & (A | B);
```

Since `Main` is equivalent to `{r: string, a: string} | {r: string, b: string}`, this works:

```
const main: Main = {
    r: 'r',
    a: 'a'
}
```

No surprises here. However, this throws the following error:

```
const func : (main: Main) => void = main => {
    main.a
    /*   ^
    * [TS2339]
    * Property 'a' doesn't exist on type 'Main'.
    *   Property 'a' doesn't exist on type 'Root & B' */
}
```

I do understand that `.a` doesn't exist on `Root & B`, but it exists on `Root & A`, so it must exists on `(Root & A) | (Root & B)` which is equivalent to `Main`, right?

Is it a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right about `Main` being equivalent to `(Root & A) | (Root & B)` you are wrong about the interpretation of union types (`|`). A union type means you can assign either type in the union to `main` ( so either `(Root & A)` or `(Root & B)`), but you can only access common properties of the union members. In this case the common member is only `r`. Since `main` ca be either `(Root & A)` or `(Root & B)`, `a` might not exist on `main`, so typescript prevents such an access.

To use the members that only exist on one type in the union you need a type guard. In this case an `in` type-guard  will work best:

```
const func : (main: Main) => void = main => {
    if ('a' in main) {
        main.a
    } else {
        main.b
    }
}
```

You can read more about type guards [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 2):

There's the problem that the compiler can't make sure that either `.a` or `.b` are available at this point, because that's going to be validated within runtime. As soon as you create a variable of type `Main`, you'll specify what specialized type of Main it is. So either `Root & A` or `Root & B`.

To make sure that `.a` or `.b` are accessible within that function just do the following:

```
type Root = { r: string };
type AB = { a?: string, b?: string };
type Main = Root & AB;

const func = (main: Main): void => {
    if ('a' in main) {
        main.a!
    } else {
        main.b!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the typeguard idea! I accepted Titian's answer because it doesn't changes my type definitions though