# Union Array types in Flow. Property is missing in Type A but exists in type B

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How can I tell flow that I am using one or the other type?

Here's an example of my problem:

```
/* @flow */

type Student = {
  role: string,
};

type Teacher = {
  role: string,
  title: string
};

const teachersArray: Array<Teacher> = [{role: 'teacher', title: 'mr' }];
const studentsArray: Array<Student> = [{role: 'student'}];

let dataArray: Array<Student | Teacher> = [];

let containerType = 'course'

if (containerType === 'course') {
  dataArray = teachersArray 
} else {
  dataArray = studentsArray
}

console.log(dataArray[0].title) // Cannot get `dataArray[0].title` because property `title` is missing in `Student` [1].
```

Here's is a [try flow url](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKGArgCZ4B2GYAvGAN6phgBOcMeAXGAM4asAlpQDmAGlQBfANzps+MABU8AQwDGACzys6jZmw7c+A4eP0ZBGTj35DRU2ajVxK-MBlWbtvAIKtWKlg8fgFYADzK6lqsAHy6ANoM7NZgAOQeUdqpYu6WKakAtqypYJIAurLOrjT85FQYvv6BwU3hxHXUcfSJyUaptRTUqeWOnDRkKhgqIc1gM22kgzQAPkqe0V1g8RXoY2BVU8LairgE9KnOJKy8eKnoglBgABQHKkesJwq032mX17cASj0LAmU3mugyXmu8wAkFIwHgYDdgWBQdNWroBvVGqEpOgqrxDAA6eAiJ5o+bxAAMZSJFiseAB6CAA).

I want to be able to use the same `dataArray` but flow does not know which one I am using.

Comment: That's super weird. `const c: Array<{x: number}|{y: number}> = [{x: 10}, {y: 20}];` should trigger the same error, but works. Time to [open an issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues)?

Comment: Also, I had a [somewhat similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743887/ts2339-property-doesnt-exist-on-type-error-in-an-apparently-valid-ts-file)

Comment: Regardless whether that's an issue or not, I think the correct approach is that both `Student` and `Teacher` should extend another class and `dataArray` should be an array of that class. Otherwise, you may think about using an interface instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using the spread syntax forces Flow to check types in a different way. This doesn't throw any error:

```
if (containerType === 'course') {
  dataArray = [...teachersArray]
} else {
  dataArray = [...studentsArray]
}
```

However, Flow is right about the error here:

```
dataArray[0].title
```

Since `dataArray`'s type is `Array<Student|Teacher>`, you can't be sure that the `title` property will be defined in the first element of `dataArray`.