# Defining object shape variants in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define an object that can either contain data or an error.

```js
export type ActionResult = {
  data: any;
} | {
  error: any;
};

function test():ActionResult {
    return {
        data: 3
    }
}
```

When trying to access result of the function I get:

```js
const v = test();
v.data = 23; // Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ActionResult'.  Property 'data' does not exist on type '{ error: any; }'
```

What's the correct way of accessing either 'data' or 'error'?

Comment: Related: [`Property doesn't exist on type` error in an apparently valid TS file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53743887/8186898)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how TypeScript understands your code:

```
const v = test();
// v: {data: any} | {error: any}
v.data = 23;
// It is possible that 'v' is of type '{error: any}'
// In this case, an error might happen at runtime
// This error must be prevented right now - time to throw a TS error!
```

One way to make sure that this won't happen is to use a [type guard](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html) to restrict the union type to a type that won't throw a TS error:

```
const v = test();
// v: {data: any} | {error: any}
if ('data' in v) {
  // v: {data: any}
  v.data = 23;
  // no error!
}
```

You can also tell TypeScript that you're sure that `v` will have `data` by casting `v` when defining it:

```
const v = (test() as {data: any});
v.data = 23;
```

Check this code on [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYCUIGcCuAbYKAXigG8ATAQ2EoC4pLUQBfKAHzIgCcvkv7GLANwAoOGiyFg2YPQAUASmIA+WAhQZs+QiUUqocitTpQAzMwWixEwgDdiUaZMWiA9K6i2AdFRoOALEJQ7o4AFrwA7lhQ3LxcIogAZgYA5L6UKVCIqJ5KpCJQhZ4+xg4ArKLMItaoklARDnJOwHqU0UY0AkwWohElfiQAbEJAA)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to explicitly say: "I know the result will only have data, and will NOT have error" ?

Comment: @reflog since you named your type `ActionResult`, I assume you're going to use this to type your API responses. If so, I would strongly recommend that you overthink your design. Your endpoints should not return two different models depending if there was an error or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution with a discriminated union (I've added a common property dataType to each union member):

```
export type ActionResult = {
  dataType: "value",  
  data: any
} | {
  dataType: "error",  
  error: any
};

function test():ActionResult {
    return {
        dataType: "value",
        data: 3
    }
}

const v = test();
if ("value" === v.dataType){
   v.data = 23;
}
```