# how to use TypeScript union types properly?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, union-types

I'm having trouble with basic union types, appreciate some help!
Building a chat app where incoming messages can have a payload of a varying type. So I created a few payload types like:

```
export interface TextPayload {
  text: string,
}
export interface ImagePayload {
  url: string,
} //etc
```

bound them all up in a union type just to be clear, using `|`

```
export type MessagePayload = TextPayload | ImagePayload | UrlPayload | FilePayload
```

and then the final Message uses that as the payload.

```
export interface IBotMsg {
  payload: MessagePayload  // this creates the problem
}
```

but when trying to use I get this error

```
[0]       TS2459: Type 'MessagePayload' has no property 'text' and no string index signature.
```

The code is used here. Possibly its the destructuring assignment is confusing the type system...

```
  const msg: IBotMsg = req.body.msg
  const { payload: { text } } = msg
```

another line throwing error

```
    let text = msgIn.payload.text
```

Full error

```
[0]
[0] ERROR in ./server/bots/watson/routes/index.ts
[0] [tsl] ERROR in /Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/server/bots/watson/routes/index.ts(19,22)
[0]       TS2459: Type 'MessagePayload' has no property 'text' and no string index signature.
[0]
[0] ERROR in ./server/bots/watson/routes/index.ts
[0] [tsl] ERROR in /Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/server/bots/watson/routes/index.ts(40,25)
[0]       TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'MessagePayload'.
[0]   Property 'text' does not exist on type 'ImagePayload'.
[0]
[0] ERROR in ./server/bots/tix/brain/TixBrain.ts
[0] [tsl] ERROR in /Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/server/bots/tix/brain/TixBrain.ts(27,30)
[0]       TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'MessagePayload'.
[0]   Property 'text' does not exist on type 'ImagePayload'.
[0]
[0] ERROR in /Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/server/bots/testbot/TestBot.ts
[0] [tsl] ERROR in /Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/server/bots/testbot/TestBot.ts(12,39)
[0]       TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'MessagePayload'.
[0]   Property 'text' does not exist on type 'ImagePayload'.
```

it's almost as if the compiler just bailed halfway on ImagePayload...

Does a union type mean properties have to exist on **every** member, not just one? The subtypes have to be a superset of the interface? I don't quite see the point in that case.
I did also try with just `TextPayload`, eg not a union type and got a similar error... confused.

I'm also a little confused between types and interfaces. Why isn't this a `UnionInterface` ?

Thanks for any tips.

MS reference
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

full code

```
export enum MessageType {
  TEXT = 0,
  IMAGE = 1,
  URL_LINK = 2,
  FILE = 3,
}

export interface TextPayload {
  text: string,
  mention?: string[],
}

export interface ImagePayload {
  url: string,
}

export interface UrlPayload {
  sourceUrl: string,
  title: string,
  summary: string,
  imageUrl: string,
}

export interface FilePayload {
  url: string,
  name: string,
}

export type MessagePayload = TextPayload | ImagePayload | UrlPayload | FilePayload

export interface IBotMsg {
  chatId?: string,
  token?: string,
  messageType?: MessageType
  payload: MessagePayload  // this creates the problem
}
```

Comment: `Does a union type mean properties have to exist on every member, not just one?` - no, that's what [intersection types are for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855908/naming-of-typescripts-union-and-intersection-types)

Comment: `I'm also a little confused between types and interfaces. Why isn't this a UnionInterface ?` - if you want an interface that has all the properties from a number of other interfaces, just declare an interface that extends them all. Union and intersection are operations defined on types, and they produce types, not interfaces - interface is one particular kind of type, there are many others types which are not expressible as interfaces.

Comment: thanks but actually I want a flexible `payload` type that may or may not have the `.text` member depending on `messageType`. So is that not possible with Unions?

Comment: It's possible, you just have to make sure that the object you received does indeed have the property that you want to access - usually it's done using [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) and switch or if statement that checks the `kind` property which is present in all union member types

Comment: In your case, the compiler has no way of knowing that the actual type of `MessagePayload` depends on the value of `messageType` - you can use type assertion or custom type guard to go around that, but putting `messageType` into payload and making `MessagePayload` a discriminated union type would be simpler IMO.

Comment: you make it sound simple! OK, its `any` for now and I'll dig into this later. Thanks! If you want to make an answer I can accept it later..

Answer (score 1):

Here's why TypeScript is throwing an error - it's trying to do good actually, but coding things right can be tricky (trust me, [I've been there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53743887/8186898), and [also there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823822/8186898)):

```
// so let's say we have:
const msg: IBotMsg = ...

// if we write
msg.payload.text // it fails because msg could be equal to {payload:{url:'...'}}
msg.payload.url  // it fails because msg could be equal to {payload:{text:'...'}}
// so TypeScript prevents that and throws an error.

// You have to make clear to TypeScript that you know which properties you expect, either using typegards:
if ('text' in msg.payload) {
    msg.payload.text;
}

// ... or by casting:
const msg2: {payload: TextPayload} = (msg as {payload: TextPayload});
msg2.payload.text; // no error
msg2.payload.url;  // rightful error
```

Check out this code live [in the TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQB5gApwJ4A2A9nACbIDeykWAXMgM5hSgDmyAvgFCiSyIoAkgFs4rCLkIlyVAK5QC9JixDtuYPAAcUAWQgMGYifmJlkAXjSYcJ6cgA+yEUcmnSAbh7ho8JE4BCRGA6DOxUmrZk9HoGLpHknFxcCEQgTMjCofSCgcGhFpTIEVJRhTRg9ADkABYQBMSVnNyZrAB0xW6t5Z4t7fGt8gSePDDIABSV5Y2gGaF9JaQAlJRcyGuzbR3SXdae3Mmp6S0ATPQUW6XoWK7SHAVjLchwDJQXpPRXNgsciz2hx-NOt0uCdAdtBu4gA)

Comment: wow thanks, I think I understand now, will play with it and check! thanks for the nice comments ex.